# Deque: deepcopy required on append

Tags: python, deque

I require to add a large number of dictionaries to a list.  Using list, I saw a considerable slow-down as the size grew, taking seconds in later cases, from memory allocations.

I moved to *deque*, with its fast append:
The loader below steps through a large json object, processing each "line".  The result is a dictionary and this dictionary is appended to a deque.

The "surprise" was that as I added each dictionary, the other, existing dictionaries in the deque all updated to the same values.  So, the early appended dicts were now the same as the last.  I did not see this behaviour with a standard python list.

I managed to fix this by using a *deepcopy*, but what is going on here?

```
for i, security in enumerate(json_object['securities']):  
                    _processed_line =  Loader.processLine(security)
                    _loadlist.append(deepcopy(_processed_line))
```

Comment: This behavior wouldn't happen simply because you changed from a list to a deque. They're both just containers for references to objects, and if you add duplicate references to each of the containers, they'll behave the same in that regard. You must have changed something else, or just didn't notice this behavior with lists. Also note, lists have fast appends. It's fast *prepend*s that you need a deque for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice.  The problem appears to be that the appended variable, which is then recalculated, has been appended with a reference.  In other words, as I append a new item, the previously appended contents of the dicts update to the values of the new items.

A shallow copy was sufficient to resolve this.  A deepcopy ultimately causing a memory error due to the size of the deque.

```
_loadlist.append(copy(_processed_line))
```